# Is there a way to let the interpreter know the second path is the same as the first path in the terminal?

Tags: command-line

Maybe the title is a bit confusing, so here is an example

for instance I am at the root

```
mv /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/camera-shutter.oga \
  /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/camera-shutter.temp
```

in this single command the path is the same only the filename change. It might seem really trivial but I write a lot of commands like this one and I always feel losing so much time to write. I use zsh and there is path completion but still too tedious, I also know how to copy/paste in the terminal but I don't like using the mouse. I know `!$` modifier but it's for inter commands, it doesn't work for inline.
Technically I wish I could type the command, the path and then maybe a shortcut to repeat the previous dirpath or even better a modifier like `!$` if it exists.
If no such feature exist native, how would you do that ? any idea, tricks ? the shorter the better.
Thanks in advance

Comment: mv /path/to/camera-shutter.{oga,temp}

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access history expansion for the current line in both bash and zsh using the *event designator* `!#`

So for example to grab the last argument `$` of the current line `!#` and substitute `.temp` in place of `.oga`:

```
mv /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/camera-shutter.oga !#$:s/.oga/.temp
```

Alternatively, in bash, zsh and other shells that support *brace expansion* you could simply do

```
mv /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/camera-shutter.{oga,temp}
```

Note that brace expansion works differently from shell globbing - it does not care whether the result matches an existing file or not.